# Does the Cantor Set with Irrational Endpoints Contain Rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

1. Let $[a,b]$ be a nonempty interval with irrational endpoints.
2. Choose distinct irrational points $p,q\in(a,b)$
3. Remove the subinterval $(p,q)$ from the initial interval $[a,b]$
4. Repeat the process similar to the Cantor set process, choosing **irrational** endpoints at each stage.

**Does the resultant set contain rational points?**

Comment: I am trying to invent an example of a perfect set which contains irrational numbers only, but I am stuck with this step and cannot tell if the set has irrational numbers only.

Comment: I invite those hitting the down button to my question offer an explanation for what you think is wrong with my question

Comment: It depends on the points you pick in each stage.  Can you find a way to pick them to make sure there wouldn't be any rational points?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah I see, the irrational endpoints can be picked to converge to a rational point.

Comment: You might find it interesting that although it seems difficult to find a nonempty perfect set containing only irrational numbers, if you take the usual Cantor set $C$ (or any nonempty perfect nowhere dense set, for that matter), then there exists a real number $x$ such that if you translate $C$ by $x,$ then you'll get such an irrational Cantor set. Moreover (and this is the really interesting part), there are so many such $x$'s that work in this way that there are uncountably many such $x$'s in every open interval, no matter how small or where the interval is located.

Comment: I think it's difficult to show that you can make this construction work without first showing that there is a perfect set of irrationals. The "usual" way of doing this is by finding a compact subset of irrationals with no isolated points (or, equivalently, an uncountable compact subset - then you can just pass to the CB core).

Comment: @tomasz (in case you're interested): Regarding my comment 12 hours ago about translates of the Cantor set, I was in a hurry then and didn't have time to look up something I'd written a while back that gives more details and references --- these can be found in [this 11 May 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Vj56y59Ll6k/m/8WuJkD0uVM4J).